# Server wait period after DNS lookup is way too slow

Tags: performance, page-speed, dns-lookup

I'm trying to optimize the speed of my portfolio site as much as possible, which considering its a static website shouldn't take much.

I'm using cloudflare to manage my DNS, DigitalOcean's droplet to run NGINX, express to serve compiled Jade/Stylus files as HTML/CSS.

When I use a tool like pingdom to measure the time it takes for requests, I find that the DNS lookup takes 0.2s and the server takes 0.1s

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vxCFFXt.png]

When using GTMetrix, its a bit of a different story, it takes dramatically longer for the wait period.

[image]

Despite running all my images through a CDN, caching all my pages - using prerender; I find that a lot of sloppy websites with almost no optimization, load in a similar time to mine, with much larger page sizes (1.7mb vs my 240kb)

One thing that could be happening is that my server is somehow overloaded by a request and so it takes a little longer to serve a page. Or I'm not properly caching my files. Either way doesn't explain the 200ms DNS lookup. And when retesting my site on pingdom I somehow drop all the way down to 20ms wait times too. But DNS lookup times of 200ms are constant.

I have an AAAA record pointing my ipv6 address to my domain, an A record pointing my ipv4 address to my domain, and some additional A records pointing to subdomains, while my only 2 CNAMEs point to email subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I had cloudflare proxy enabled on my A records, bad idea because it added bloat to my TTFB.

Comment: Ironically, [CloudFlare says to not worry about TTFB](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ttfb-time-to-first-byte-considered-meaningles/). Not sure I trust them on that though.

Comment: Yeah I read that article, it felt a lot like PR backtracking. I reduced my page load speed from 2s+ to just 1s by not using their proxy servers, whether or not TTFB is a big deal to them is irrelevant when I saw an actual quantifiable improvement by worrying about it.